# Filtering Hough transform to only find horizontal and vertical lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to write some code that will find lines in an image and draw a red line over the found lines. I've managed to do this using the Hough transform but my problem is I need it to only find horizontal and vertical lines and leave out lines of all other slopes.

I figure that I could solve this by finding the slope of the lines that the code finds and only display red lines over the horizontal and vertical lines using an if statement, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract the x and y values from the points I find.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to solve this problem?

Here is my code below:

```
function findlineshv(I)

% Read Image
img = imread(I);

% Convert to black and white because
% edge function only works with BW imgs
bwImage = rgb2gray(img);

% figure(1),imshow(bwImage);

% find edges using edge function
b=edge(bwImage,'sobel');

% show edges
% figure(1),imshow(b);


% compute the Hough transform of the edges found
% by the edge function
[hou,theta,rho] = hough(b);

% define peaks, x and y
peaks = houghpeaks(hou,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(hou(:))));

x = theta(peaks(:,2));
y = rho(peaks(:,1));


lines = houghlines(bwImage,theta,rho,peaks,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);

figure, imshow(bwImage), hold on

for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',3,'Color','red');
end
```

Comment: Just a hint: You might get a quicker response if you also share your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using required Theta range as answered earlier. Adding this to mention that the Theta range has to be within [-90, 90).

- For Horizontal line detection, use range -90:-85 (modify limits as required)
- For Vertical line detection, use range -3:3 (modify limits as required)

```
    I  = imread('circuit.tif');I = edge(I,'canny');
    %% Hough Transform based Horizontal line detection
    [H,theta,rho] = hough(I,'Theta',-90:0.5:-85);
    P = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
    lines = houghlines(I,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',3);
    figure, imshow(I), hold on
    max_len = 0;
    for k = 1:length(lines)
       xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
       plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
    
       % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
       plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
       plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
    
       % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
       len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
       if ( len > max_len)
          max_len = len;
          xy_long = xy;
       end
    end
    
    % highlight the longest line segment
    plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
```

[image]

Changing the angle limits as following yields vertical lines:

```
[H,theta,rho] = hough(I,'Theta',-3:0.5:-3);
```

[image]

Ref: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/hough-transform.html

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by simply setting the desired theta values in the Hough function.

```
start_angle = 80;
end_angle = 100;
theta_resolution = 0.5:

[H,T,R] = hough(b, 'Theta', start_angle:theta_resolution:end_angle);
```

Comment: This does not work, since 'Theta' must be within [-90, (90-ThetaResolution)].